# sp_executesql not executing dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the value of two variables from dynamic sql .

```
declare @sImport_Table1 table 
 (
   Id int identity(1,1) ,
   Zone nvarchar(50),
   Sub_Code nvarchar(50),
   Geography nvarchar(50),
   DayOfWeek nvarchar(50)
 )



INSERT INTO @sImport_Table1 SELECT 'A','Z','Geo','SUN'

declare @sZone nvarchar(50)
declare @sSubCode nvarchar(50)
declare @c_Geography nvarchar(50)='Geo'
declare @c_DayOfWeek nvarchar(50)='SUN'
declare @sImport_Table nvarchar(500)='@sImport_Table1'



--SELECT * FROM @sImport_Table1
declare @sQuery nvarchar(4000) 

SET @sQuery='SELECT @sZone = Zone, '+
                   '@sSubCode = Sub_Code
          FROM '+ @sImport_Table +
         ' WHERE Geography ='''+ @c_Geography + '''
          AND [DayOfWeek] = '''+ @c_DayOfWeek +''''

PRINT @sQuery 

sp_executesql @sQuery)

PRINT @sZone 
PRINT @sSubCode
```

Comment: @marc_s sorry i will take care of that .

Comment: @rahularyansharma you should accept answers when a solution solves the problem you have or at least response to answer that are not helpful, I have just seen your previously asked question and it seems you are a bit reluctant to accept answers, This community is not there to help one individual but anyone who is part of it. You not accepting an answer can prompt other users to ask similar questions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to declare this table variable inside the Dynamic sql as dynamic sql has its own scope, variable declared outside of dynamic sql are not visible inside dynamic sql.

And also use OUTPUT clause when trying to retrieve values from a dynamic sql query. Something like this....

```
declare @sZone nvarchar(50)
declare @sSubCode nvarchar(50)
declare @c_Geography nvarchar(50)='Geo'
declare @c_DayOfWeek nvarchar(50)='SUN'
declare @sImport_Table nvarchar(500)='@sImport_Table1'



--SELECT * FROM @sImport_Table1
declare @sQuery nvarchar(MAX); --<-- to be on safe side 

SET @sQuery = N' declare @sImport_Table1 table 
                     (
                       Id int identity(1,1) ,
                       Zone nvarchar(50),
                       Sub_Code nvarchar(50),
                       Geography nvarchar(50),
                       DayOfWeek nvarchar(50)
                     )
               INSERT INTO @sImport_Table1 SELECT ''A'',''Z'',''Geo'',''SUN''

               SELECT @sZone = Zone, @sSubCode = Sub_Code ' +
              N' FROM @sImport_Table1 ' + 
              N' WHERE Geography =  @c_Geography  ' +
              N' AND [DayOfWeek] =  @c_DayOfWeek '

PRINT @sQuery 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sQuery
                     ,N'@c_Geography nvarchar(50),@c_DayOfWeek nvarchar(50),
                        @sZone nvarchar(50) OUTPUT, @sSubCode nvarchar(50) OUTPUT'
                     ,@c_Geography , @c_DayOfWeek, @sZone OUTPUT, @sSubCode OUTPUT
SELECT @sSubCode, @sZone
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace 
sp_executesql @sQuery)

with

execute sp_executesql @sQuery

Also in dynamic queries you need to declare variables inside your dynamic string.
Otherwise it will throw error.